# Pointers inside structure

Tags: c, pointers

What is the difference if I declare variables inside structure as pointers and just as normal variables?

Let say I have this structure:

```
typedef struct _inf{
     int age;
}inf, *pinf;
```

and I have 2 functions to get the age and print it but I passed the structure as a reference by a pointer

```
void getAge(pinf INF) {
    scanf("%d", &INF->age);
}

void printAge(pinf in) {
    printf("\nAge: %d", in->age);
}
```

I'm confused what if I want to declare (age) as a pointer. Does it makes any difference.

Comment: "Does it makes any difference." Do you know the basics of pointers? In which way could `int` and `int*` not be different? That's like a house compared with a piece of paper where the address of that house is printed.

Comment: I know the difference sure but I want to know if this make this value not changable during the runtime (original copy not just a copy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to declare the `age` member as a pointer, based on what you've posted here.  You're using `age` to store an integer value, not the address of another object that stores an integer value.

You're accessing the `age` member of a struct instance through a pointer to that struct instance:

```
     +---+        +-----+
INF: |   | -----> | age |  
     +---+        +-----+
```

so any change you make to `INF->age` will be reflected in whatever struct object `INF` points to.  For example, if your code is

```
inf foo;
getAge( &foo );
printAge( &foo );
```

then the following are all true:

```
 INF      ==  in         == &foo      // pinf == pinf == pinf
*INF      == *in         ==  foo      // inf  == inf  == inf

 INF->age ==  (*INF).age ==  foo.age  // int   == int   == int
&INF->age == &(*INF).age == &foo.age  // int * == int * == int *
 in->age  ==  (*in).age  ==  foo.age  // int   == int   == int
```

A few words on style:

You should not use leading underscores in variable or type names - names with leading underscores are reserved for use by the implementation.  Use `struct inf` instead of `struct _inf`.

Secondly, resist the urge to use typedefs.  Especially resist the urge to hide pointers behind typedefs.  If the user of the type has to be aware of its "pointer-ness" to use it properly (such as whether to use `.` or `->` to access members, or whether to use `*` to dereference it), then *don't* hide it behind a typedef.

"Leaky" abstractions like that lead to code that's hard to read and maintain.  Either write a full API that handles all the pointer operations, or leave the pointer-ness exposed.

Comment: This means that it doesn't matter because I passed the structure as a reference (structure address) , so any change inside members will be fixed even if I pass this structure to another function. Am I right?

Comment: @MohannadRaafat: Yes - the change to `INF->age` is also a change to `foo.age`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help